# Firebase import sorted data

Tags: javascript, web, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to import sorted data from a Firebase database.

As an example:
I have a small company and I need to import the data of all employers. 
I am `owner_01` which means I would have to import all the users whose child `owner_uid` match `owner_01`.

The data will be used on a website, which means I will be using `javascript`.

Here you have the JSON :

```
    {
  "Owner_users" : {
    "owner_01" : {
      "email" : "owner_01@gmail.com",
      "uid" : 123
    },
    "owner_02" : {
      "email" : "owner_02@gmail.com",
      "uid" : 12345
    }
  },
  "Users" : {
    "user_01" : {
      "Email" : "asd@ghita.com",
      "Name" : "asd",
      "age" : 23,
      "owner_uid" : 123,
      "uid" : "asd"
    },
    "user_02" : {
      "Email" : "all@gmail.com",
      "Name" : "all",
      "age" : 49,
      "owner_uid" : 123,
      "uid" : "asdfg"
    },
    "user_03" : {
      "age" : 60,
      "email" : "ovenre@gmail.com",
      "owner_uid" : 12345,
      "uid" : "sdfzsvsvsd"
    }
  }
}
```

Check [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMWQv.jpg) url to see how the database is structured.
**Update:**

HTML code:

```
<table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Email</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>uid</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="usersData">
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

JS code

```
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('Users')
var query = usersRef.orderByChild('owner_uid').equalTo('123');
query.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {

  var email = snap.child("Email").val;
  var name = snap.child("Name").val;
  var uid = snap.child("uid").val;

  $("#usersData").append("<tr><td" + email + "</td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + uid + "</td></tr>");

});
```

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for advice! I uploaded the JSON tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('Users')
var query = usersRef.orderByChild('owner_uid').equalTo('YOUR UID HERE');
query.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val().uid);
});
```

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried this and I think I am missing something could you please point me if I am doing something wrong? I updated the HTML and the js code/=.

Comment: `var email = snap.child("Email").val` -> `var email = snap.child("Email").val()`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry about that. I modified all the missing () but it still doesn't show me in my table the info i wanna import.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i modified  function(snapshot) to snap=> and it is working but i don't know why.

Comment: That should indeed not make a difference. But good to hear that it works. Happy hacking!